# POST or GET PHP values within while loop using modal

Tags: jquery, post, mysqli, while-loop, modal-dialog

Below is mysqli query of users that are displayed in a while loop table with first names in one column and a clickable link in the other column. I would like to click OPEN that uses javascript or even something else like jquery to open modal overlay screen and click the message button that will POST or send PHP value to same page or another. The problem below is that only the first $id_friend shows in modal depending whether its in or out of loop. Please help find the best way to retrieve these values safely and easy.

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  ?>

 $id_friend = $row['id_friend'];

 $firstName = $row['firstName'];


<table>
<tr>
<td><a><?php echo $firstName;  ?></a></td>
<td>

<!-- opens modal -->

<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row['friend_id'];?>" onclick="show(this.id)" >open </a>

<!-- modal -->

<div id="myNav2" class="overlay2">

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn2" 
onclick="closeNav233()">&times;</a>

  <div class="overlay2-content">
     <div>
<form  action="getuser2.php" method="POST">
<button  name="friend_id" value="<?php echo $id_friend; ?>" 
type="submit">MESSAGE</button>
<input  class="friend_id" type="hidden" name="friend_id" value="<?php echo 
$id_friend; ?>" >
</form>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>

<?php
 } //end of while loop
?> 

</table>

<script>
function show() {

document.getElementById("myNav2").style.width = "100%"; //opens modal

option = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(option ); //to check clicked id is Ok

$.ajax({
    url: 'testmodal.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {option : id},
    success: function(data) {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
    document.getElementById('myNav2').innerHTML =data;
    }
});

}

</script>

<style>
body {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay2 {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay2-content {
position: relative;
top: 25%;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay2 a {
padding: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 36px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay2 a:hover, .overlay2 a:focus {
color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay2 .closebtn2 {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 45px;
font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay2 a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay2 .closebtn2 {
  font-size: 40px;
   top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
 }
 }
</style>

<script>

function closeNav233() {
document.getElementById("myNav2").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{
$row['post_id'].$row['post_title'].$row['content']; 

}
```

this is how the columns in a row can be fetched you are using some previously initialised data when using first_name and friend_id

Comment: Thanks but whether I use $row['friend_id'] or initialized data like $friend_id it only echos the first or last $friend_id in a Modal overlay depending on whether its in the loop or out. Works fine on the page with the table. I think I need Ajax.

Comment: Can I see an example of this so i can understand , i feel May be I have not understood the question correctly